# Policy for EC2 and ELB based on number of transcoding processes on each instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, policy, autoscaling, amazon-elb

I need to transcode massive number of audio files on a series of auto-scaling instances behind an ELB. The core of transcoding script is based on Node.Js and FFMPEG. Queuing is impossible because users are not patience! I need to control the number of transcodings on each instance to avoid CPU 100% problem.

**My questions:**

**A-** Is there any way to define a policy for ELB to control the number of connections to each instance? if not is there any parameter to control average CPU utilization on each instance and add a new one after triggering level? (I have found [this](http://www.slideshare.net/8KMiles/cloud-computing-autoscaling-amazon-ec2-4829409) slide but it is not complete) If it adds a new instance on the fly how much it takes time the new instance be 100% operative to serve the user ( I mean does auto scaling have long latency?)

**B-** Is there another alternative architecture to achieve same transcoding solution? (I have included my current idea to this answer as a drawing). I can not use third party solutions like Transcoding.com I need to have my native solution.

**C-** I use node.js for each instance and by socket to the user browser show progress. From browser side I send regularly some ajax request to the node.js side to get the progress information. Does this mechanism has problem with sticky session?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use an AWS SDK. Normally you'd use one of the official ones for C#, Ruby etc. Since you're on node.js, try using this SDK on github to monitor, throttle and create instance connection pools etc.

https://github.com/awssum/awssum

there's also AWS2JS

https://github.com/SaltwaterC/aws2js

Answer (score 1):

If your scaling needs to take place in response to individual requests on the server (i.e. a single request would require X number of machines to execute in desired timeframe), then autoscaling is probably not going to be the answer for you, as you will have delay as the new instances become active.  You will also potentially have much higher cost to run service in such manner as you could scale up and time a number of times in response to individual request, charging you for one hour minimum for each instance that is started.

If however you are concerned with autoscaling, to for example, increase your fleet 50%  during peak times when you get request volume spikes (i.e. you already have many servers serving many requests, but you just need to keep latency down during peak hours by adding more instances), then autoscaling should probably work just fine for you.

There are any number of triggers you can configure to control scaling events in such a case.

ELB does support session affinity ("sticky" sessions).